# How To Hidden Password in URL

Tags: laravel, function, view, controller, routes

i dont know how hidden password on url 
i got problem like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/bulletin/%201/edit?passwordC=11111&page=1

My View

```
<form>
                        <div class="form-row" style="specified-width:200; position: absolute; bottom:0; margin-bottom:10">
                            <input style="width:150px" type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="passwordC">
                            <input type="hidden"  value="{{$buletin->currentPage()}}" name="page">
                            <button style="margin:0 5px" formAction="/bulletin/ {{ $tampil_B->id }}/deleteOper" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            <button formAction='(url(edit))' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

My Router

```
route::get('/bulletin/{id}/edit','BulletinController@edit');
```

my controller

```
  public function edit (Request $request, $id)
{
    $buletin = \App\Dashboard::find($id);
    $url = "/?page={$request->page}";



    if(is_null($buletin->password)){

        $request->session()->flash('failed', 'Cant Edit Because this post not had been set  password ');
        return view('bulletin.edit_nopass', ['buletin' => $buletin,'url'=> $url]);

    }

    if (hash::check($request->passwordC,$buletin->password)){
        return view ('bulletin.edit', ['buletin' => $buletin, 'url'=> $url]);//save and go back to card

        } else {

            $request->validate([
                'passwordC' => 'required|required_with:password|same:password'
                ],[
                'passwordC.required_with' => "Password not match",
                'passwordC.required' => "Password Required",
                'passwordC.same' => "The Password You Entered Do Not Match.Please Try Again"
                    ]);
                }
```

Comment: use Post method

Comment: can u post your whole edit action codes?

Comment: that i show on top

Comment: so do u update something in your action

Comment: nope, still same

Comment: so what is this method for?

Comment: ya its method if u going will do update, and need password to check u are the person who post bulletin

Comment: so why don't you just put the checking code and update code together?

Comment: no i checking first before do update, if the user are authentic they can update, if no yeah u know

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a byproduct of how you have written this solution. To remove the password from the URL, you will have to find a different mechanism to get to the edit page.

As it currently stands, you are doing a GET request to the edit page from the form, and because it is a GET request, the form parameters are sent in the URL.

From the edit controller method you are then returning a view, so the URL is never re-written.

That is **why** you have this problem, as to how you could solve this, there are many options; you could post to an endpoint that stores the approval in a session that you then check in middleware, or in the controller, and then return the view. You could use the reconfirm password middleware from Laravel. Or even a POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, where you post the form and then redirect to the edit page from there with whatever you need to do to protect the edit endpoint.

There are many options, but its impossible to tell you how to solve this problem given that you need to rethink how you will solve it.

Comment: i cant understand sir,

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not correct to send with `GET` .But if it is very vital you have two way:

1.use `encrypt` .but it is not safe too.because there is even online sites that can decrypte .
2.use `Hash:make` . Hashing is an unilateral.It means that you can not dehash it